# Generating random tunnels over a layer for a 2D game in Racket

Tags: algorithm, scheme, racket, render

A project I'm working on requires me to randomly generate a set of tunnels, of variable length over a layer which has a texture printed on it on a separately generated window. How can I best handle this?
Edit: I know how to print the background, but I have no idea on how to implement tunnels for a 2D game. I'm working with `#lang racket` on this project, and have been provided with a file, that when called forth using the `(require ...)` procedure, I can use it to create a window with a given resolution.

Comment: AFAIK Scheme doesn't have any graphics libraries defined in their standard. Is there a special implementation that you might have forgot to tag?

Comment: I have received a program that allows Scheme to creat a separate window. I have managed to fill that window with a texture, but on top of that, I wish to create some tunnels, that are generated when the application is run. This is the first time I've had to do something like this, so excuse if I wasn't thorough enough.

Comment: You need to supply which scheme implementation you use since the Scheme standard R5RS doesn't have any such features. Most of them have just terminal and file capabilities. Eg. there is a Scheme derived dialect thats called `racket` that only runs under the implementation Racket that has lots of libraries, but it's not R5RS. It may have support for opening windows, but it's only one out of many many R5RS implementations.

Comment: Well, on the first line I've written '#lang racket'. Then a (require ...) procedure where I call the file I've been given to use in my implementation.

Comment: Thats `#lang racket` and not standard Scheme. You should tag `racket` and perhaps give som code on how a tunnel is made.

Comment: That is part of the question I'm asking, I haven't been given more have I written such a procedure.

Comment: Maybe this will be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm